# Как отключить сообщения cURL?

Tags: php, curl, ftp

Добрый день. Есть код на PHP который получает список файлов с FTP сервера. Код работает через прокси, который поддерживает режим FTP over HTTP. Вот
сам код

```
$proxy_host = "1.1.1.1";  
$proxy_port = 8080;  
$curl = curl_init();  
$ftp_url = 'ftp://login:password@ftp:21/dir'; 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy_host);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,$proxy_port);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,'login_proxy:password_proxy');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$ftp_url); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  
$content=curl_exec($curl);
echo $content;
```

Код работает прекрасно, однако вывод списка файлов всегда предваряет сообщение
`curl 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /`. Это сообщение присутствует даже тогда когда я пытаюсь скачать файлы. То есть содержимое всех скачанных файлов содержит это диагностическое сообщение. Как отключить вывод этого сообщения?

Дополнение
Параметр **CURLOPT_VERBOSE** (true,false,отсутствует) никак не влияет на сообщение. Есть подозрение что он включен по умолчанию и не отключается.

Еще дополнения
пробовал на версиях PHP 5.3.13 и 5.6.30
версия curl (из phpinfo) 7.24.0
**Важно** то, что без proxy сервера все работает отлично.

Comment: Попробуйте эти настройки `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_ALL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTPPORT,'-');`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Alexus нужна информация какая версия php у вас и какая версия cUrl ? пробовали без прокси сделать запрос что приходило?

Comment: @programmer403 добавил в описание...

Comment: @Alexus ну так тогда все ясно, дело не в php а в софте прокси сервера. (да я к тому что вы не туда смотрите) попробуйте поискать в файлах конфигурации прокси сервера. может проще сменить сервер

Comment: @programmer403 спасибо. Дайте ответ на вопрос, чтобы я мог завершить конкурс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
```

Это сообщение выводится не из php, а из прокси-программы через которую вы отправляете запрос. Я не знаю что за софт там стоит может быть это 'Pure-FTPd' или что-то в этом роде. Но похоже что это он делает STDOUT перед показом того что вы запросили.. и соответственно ваш курл уже все это и подтягивает.

Нужно уже смотреть в сторону как это заглушить, отправить в > /dev/null, смотреть конфиги и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Если внимательно прочитать

> CURLOPT_VERBOSE : TRUE для вывода подробной информации. Записывает
>   вывод в STDERR или файл, указанный с помощью CURLOPT_STDERR.

По скольку `CURLOPT_VERBOSE - FALSE` ничего не сказано, и притом в вашем случае он не соответствует логическому продолжению,то думаю что с использованием опции `CURLOPT_STDERR` поможет решить вашу проблему.

**Замените:**

```
.....
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,FALSE);
.....
```

**На:**

> Заранее создайте файл `curl.txt`

```
.....
$stderr = fopen("curl.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $stderr);
.....
```

Comment: В файл выводит много дополнительной информации, ОДНАКО строка осталась.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте опции `CURLOPT_HEADER` или `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` (а, вероятно, и обе вместе) поставить в `false`. [Тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) описаны дополнительные опции, пошарьтесь в них если не помогло.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пробовал все 4 варианта с CURLOPT_HEADER, CURLOPT_HEADER_OUT результат прежний. Я пересмотрел все возможные опции в функции curl_setopt. Ничего похожего на проблему не нашел.

Comment: а `CURLOPT_NOBODY`? А другие варианты, которые могут помочь? Вы просмотрели полностью всю документацию?

Comment: CURLOPT_NOBODY (уже пробовал) ничего кроме заголовков не возвращает.

Comment: Выводит список файлов из корневой директории или из /dir